# jQuery .each() can't find elements in woocommerce header cart list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to hide an "Add to cart" button (this button come from a plugin, not woocommerce) in a li item from a ul. The logic I'm using in order to work dynamically is the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('div[class="lunar_woo_thumb"]').each(function(index,item){
        var prod_id = jQuery(item).data('wid');
        jQuery('a[class="remove"]').each(function(index2,item2){
            var prod_id_2 = jQuery(item2).data('product_id');
            if(prod_id == prod_id_2){
                jQuery(item).find(".addToCartBtn").addClass('hide_it');
            };
        });
    });
 });
```

As you can see, first I loop through all divs with class `lunar_woo_thumb`, and assign the value from a custom attribute to the variable `prod_id`.

Inside that loop I call another `.each()` function to loop through all a tags with the class `remove` on it. Assign a custom attribute again to another variable called `prod_id_2` and if both variables are equal then add a class `hide_it` to the find item with `.addToCartBtn`.

I tried copying the DOM html and JS to jsFiddle and the logic works fine.

But when used in the site, the inner loop never finds an `<a>` tag with class `.remove`, so it never copare both variables.

Cart's HTML is visible in devTool but not in source code.

Even if I try to do simple stuff with jQuery like changing css directly to one of the `<a>` tags inside cart in header, never happens.

Comment: Quite possible the elements or classes don't exist when your code runs and are added by other script. try pasting your code into browser console and run it from there after page loads and see if it does anything

Comment: Not too knowledgeable on woocommerce, but when selecting by class in jquery, do something like this: 'div.lunar_woo_thumb' not 'div[class="lunar_woo_thumb"]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can run the script in the console succesfuly, then the solution is to:

use jQuery event delegation, **.on()**
will allow you to handle *events on descendant elements not yet created.*

*good luck*

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.lunar_woo_thumb.addToCartBtn')
```

is the syntax for selecting by class with an intersection

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong selector in your code. When selecting on classes jQuery expects a "." in front of the classname in order to find it:

`jQuery('.lunar_woo_thumb')` instead of `jQuery('div[class="lunar_woo_thumb"]')`

Of course this also needs to happen for your second query. You probably got confused because of the way jQuery selects on name-attributes : `jQuery('[name="lunar_woo_thumb"]')`.

Answer (score 0):

charlietfl's comment in the original question made me find the answer.
I was indeed executing the script before the one that loads the cart content.

Instead of using `jQuery(document).ready` I used `jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {`

Here is the complete code:

```
jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {

    jQuery('div[class="lunar_woo_thumb"]').each(function(index,item){

        var prod_id = jQuery(item).data('wid');

        console.log(prod_id);

        jQuery('a[class="remove"]').each(function(index2,item2){

            var prod_id_2 = jQuery(item2).data('product_id');

            if(prod_id == prod_id_2){
                jQuery(item).find(".addToCartBtn").addClass('volalo');
            };
        });

    });

 });
```

Thank you all, specially charlietfl!